# webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

capabilities:[{

```
appiumVersion: '1.18.0',
platformName: 'Android',
platformVersion: '10.0',
deviceOrientation: 'portrait ',
deviceName: 'Pixel_3a_API_29_portal',
app: "/Users/sandeep/Downloads/filename.apk",
udid:"emulator-5554",
appPackage: "appPackageString",
appActivity: "appActivityString",
autoAcceptAlerts: true,
autoGrantPermissions: true,
automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
```

}]

```
port: 4723,
hostname: '0.0.0.0',
path: "/wd/hub",
runner: 'local',
services: ['appium'],
```

I have used above configuration in config.js, but it is throwing error as below::

webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Process didn't end after 10000ms (cmd: '/usr/local/bin/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime')

Answer (score 0):

Use Control+c to gracefully shut down the port which is already somewhere in use.

Or else use these commands in your terminal

1. netstat -ano|findstr "PID :4723" : This will tell you about the port which is in use

Example:

C:\Users>netstat -ano|findstr "PID :4723"
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    0.0.0.0:4723           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9100

Then use
2. taskkill /pid 9100 /f : This will kill the session gracefully